# How do I filter my dataset based on going from one value to another within a specific number of days?

Tags: r, date, dplyr, filter, lubridate

I'm trying to figure out how to subset my dataframe to include values that go from 0 to -5 in *3 days or less*. I can't seem to figure out how to code the "3 days or less" part to my filter function. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Repro:

```
library ("lubridate")
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
data <- data.frame(date = c("2020-06-08",
                            "2020-06-09",
                            "2020-06-10",
                            "2020-06-11",
                            "2020-06-12",
                            "2021-06-13",    
                            "2021-06-14",
                            "2021-06-15",
                            "2021-06-16",
                            "2021-06-17",
                            "2021-06-18",
                            "2021-06-19",
                            "2021-06-20"),
                   value = c(2,0,-7,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,0,-6,-5,10))
data$date <- as.Date(data$date)                      
head(data)
```

the new dataframe should include all the dates and values for: "0,-7,0,-6,-5" since these are the dates that go from 0 to -5 within 3 days or less.

The "0,-1,-2,-3,-4,0" should be left since it doesn't meet this condition.

I hope that makes sense!

expected output would subset the highlighted values:

[image]

final output:

[image]

Comment: could you show your expectd output please!

Comment: I'm a little confused by your premise of "from 0 to -5", is that by values, by cumulative difference, and does it include the rows in between?

Comment: it would be by values and would not include values that dont meet the conditions. so once the value goes above -5, the sequence would end and then skip to the next one that meets those conditions

Comment: Should  2020-06-12     0 not be included in the output?

Comment: i would first say no since that date doesnt go from 0 to -5 within 3 days but now im questioning myself here. I think yes it should be included since it is within 3 days of a value under -5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(group_id = as.integer(gl(n(),3,n()))) %>% 
  filter(value == 0 | value <=-5) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-group_id)
```

```
 date       value
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 2020-06-09     0
2 2020-06-10    -7
3 2020-06-12     0
4 2021-06-17     0
5 2021-06-18    -6
6 2021-06-19    -5
```

Comment: I can post another question for this, but is there a way to specify conditions for before and after the 3 day periods? like before and after this period, it has to also be under x?